# How to make child of absolute positioned parent to expand its width?

Tags: html, css, width, absolute

*There is a lot of same questions about this problem but I think I have a different case.*

Okay, I have a block with `position: fixed` with specified width and I have absolute positioned block inside it. I want to make this tooltip flexible enough to contain a lot of text (up to 2-3 lines) or just few words. But not more than 400 pixels.

I tried a lot of properties here and get no luck. Maybe you know hot to do that?

Here's the code with all required to understand styles: [codepen.io/Grawl/pen/EazNJJ](http://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/EazNJJ?editors=110)

And in a short:

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 34%;
  right: 0;
  width: 36px;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
}
.absolute p {
  /* what have I do here? */
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="absolute">
    <p>How to make this block parent have this block width?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your issue is not clear

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to wrap this absolute div inside a relative positioned div. This would give more control over the element.